# AngularJS, referencing other DOM items from a Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a navigation bar that uses a `ng-repeat` from data provided by a REST service. When we click on some of the menu items, we navigate to a new view, when we click other items we perform other tasks like show/hide menu, show information popovers, etc.

I want to show and hide the popover that is below my menu (see HTML below), now I could use a simple `ng-show` but I want to use a directive so I can reuse the functionality, and dynamically determine a position for the popover. However I don't know how to reference the popover in my directive. I am not using jQuery so I can't use a `$(#id)` selector and

Here is my HTML:

```
  <div class="container-fluid ">
    <div class="row" data-toggle-nav-popup>
        <div class="col-xs-2 main-nav-cell" data-ng-repeat="nav in mainNavigation.topNavi" data-url="{{ nav.link }}" data-ng-click="menuRedirect(nav.link)" data-ng-class="{'is-active' :  menuOpen && $index === 0 }">
            <div> {{ nav.name }} </div>
            <div class="item-counter" data-ng-show="nav.value > 0"> {{ nav.value }} </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- PopOver - default is hidden, data-ng-show was an old implementation where we fixed the CSS position and just toggled a $scope.variable -->
<div class="nav-popover" data-ng-show="showPopover">
    <div class="nav-arrow"></div>
    <div class="nav-popover-inner">
        <div class="nav-popover-content">
            <!-- content to go here...  -->
            Content Holder
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my directive, you can see I set a timeout so the `ng-repeat` is finished, I then assign a click event to the children of the directive DIV, determine the `data-url` value of the clicked it and if there is a match to my requirements I return some positioning properties from the clicked item and then use these in an algorithm (a simple sum) to change the left/top css of the `popOver` then show the popover - does anyone know how I can reference the popover in my directive or is my approach wrong?

```
.directive('toggleNavPopup', function ($timeout) {
    'use strict';
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        priority: 800,
        link: function (scope, element) {

            $timeout(function () {

                var list = angular.element(element);

                list.children().on('click', function (evt) {


                    // determine if we have clicked the 'div' with data-url === 'message'
                    if(evt.target.getAttribute('data-url') === '/message') {
                        console.log('I would like th use the following to positon the PopOver', evt.target.offsetLeft, evt.target.clientWidth);

                        // position the popOver using value, how do I reference it, no jQuery!
                    }

                });

            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: pass the `$index` of the ng-repeat as an attribute to your custom directive. e.g. `<my-custom-directive data-position={{$index}}> </my-custom-directive>` and then in the link function of the directive read the value from the attrs. `link: function(scope, element, attrs) `

Answer (score 0):

You can have your repeat like

```
data-ng-repeat="nav in mainNavigation.topNavi track by $index" 
    data-url="{{ nav.link }}" data-position={{ $index }}
```

And then in the link function of the directive:

```
  link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      url = attrs.url
      position = attrs.position

      // Do something based on the position

  }
```

Comment: I think I have confused you... or I am confused. I want to apply changes to the <div class="nav-popover"... perhaps I didn't explain myself... or I don't understand